# Increasing the tab size?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have these 4 tabs as below. The problem is whenever I increase the tabs the tab size gets smaller. Is there any solution when they can simply be scrolled horizontally and also have the same size.

```
 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Maths
    TabSpec mathspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Maths");
    mathspec.setIndicator("Maths");
    Intent mathIntent = new Intent(this, MathActivity.class);
    mathspec.setContent(mathIntent);

    // Tab for Units
    TabSpec unitsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Units");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    unitsspec.setIndicator("Units");
    Intent unitsIntent = new Intent(this, UnitsActivity.class);
    unitsspec.setContent(unitsIntent);

    // Tab for Physics
    TabSpec physicsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Physics");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    physicsspec.setIndicator("Physics");
    Intent physicsIntent = new Intent(this, PhysicsActivity.class);
    physicsspec.setContent(physicsIntent);

    // Tab for Chemistry
    TabSpec chemistryspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Chemistry");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    chemistryspec.setIndicator("Chemistry");
    Intent chemistryIntent = new Intent(this, ChemistryActivity.class);
    chemistryspec.setContent(chemistryIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(mathspec); // Adding maths tab
    tabHost.addTab(unitsspec); // Adding units tab
    tabHost.addTab(physicsspec); // Adding physics tab
    tabHost.addTab(chemistryspec); // Adding chemistry tab

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextSize(10);



    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch over to Fragments. You will never face such an issue.

See this tutorial.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implement-swiping-between-tabs-with-viewpager-in-action-bar-using-sherlock-library/

Moreover tab activity gets deprecated.